# Python script ending in SSHing the terminal into a remote server

Tags: python, ssh

I am writing a python script which I want to end by SSHing the terminal into a remote machine. I'd read about sub processes, but I don't think these would be appropriate. I would like the user then to interact with the terminal, as if they had typed `ssh user@server.path` into the terminal.

I am only conserned with it running under Ubuntu.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> import os
>>> os.execlp('ssh', 'ssh', 'user@server')
```

or

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen(['ssh', 'user@server'])
result = proc.wait()
print result
```